# Android: How to create an EditText and set it to another views position?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, spinner

I have a layout with a textView and a spinner in it. 
If the user clicks on a button I like to hide the spinner and create an editText field programmatically at the spinners position. How can I do this?

The layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_steuern"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_betraege"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl_betraege"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_betraege"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_steuer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Steuer:"
        android:textSize="18dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello first you need to add button to your xml file.I am not able to see it anywhere.

then on button click in your java class,hide the spinner and display the Edit Text view using following code:

```
   spinner=(Spinner)findViewbyId(R.id.spinner);

   EditText et = new EditText(YourActivity.this);

   spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //hides the spinner

   your_main_layout.addView(et); //dynamically adds EditText
```

You can ask if you have any further queries :)